# Is it possible to know which dependency is preventing my bundle from activating?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

From my osgi console, with the following command:

```
felix:lb
```

I get that my bundle is "installed" but not "active". I know this usually means that one of the dependencies is not satisfied, but is there a way to know which one of them?

Comment: The information should be in the log. Unresolved constraint... If you do not see any exception, it might be possible that you installed the bundle with a higher startlevel that the framework runs on...

Comment: You can also issue **start <bundle number>** after an lb to see the log in the console

Comment: Bear in mind that "installed" doesn't necessarily mean there was a problem at all. It just means the bundle has been installed and not *yet* started.